# Extract text from line number and column number

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I try to write a script which takes in params:

- range of line
- range of column

For ex: cmd filename 1 5 12 87
where 1 and 5 it's range of line
and 12 and 87 range of column

I want to extract text from these ranges.

I find something for line using head and tail but I have no idea on how i can select the corresponding columns.

**Only for windows**: batch, powershell.

---

**UPDATE 1**

**file.txt**

```
define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_GET',     'GET',     true);
define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_HEAD',    'HEAD',    true);
define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_POST',    'POST',    true);
define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_PUT',     'PUT',     true);
define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_DELETE',  'DELETE',  true);
define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_OPTIONS', 'OPTIONS', true);
define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_TRACE',   'TRACE',   true);
```

cmd file.txt 1 3 19 27

**output**:

```
                  ST_METHOD_GET',     'GET',     true);
define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_HEAD',    'HEAD',    true);
define('HTTP_REQUEST_METHO
```

I add blank a first line just for better representation.

I fact the script simulate the selection of the text from line X to line Y starting at column W (just for the first line) and eding at column Z (just for the last line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function SelectTextRange( $path, $SL, $EL, $SS , $ES)
{
  $txt = gc $path
  $txt | select -First (($EL+1)-$SL) -Skip ($SL-1) |
     % { $_.substring( ($SS-1) ,($ES-$SS+1) )}
}
```

I understand that columns and lines values are included values.

After your more accurate sample try this:

```
Function SelectTextRange( $path, $SL, $EL, $SS , $ES)
{
  $txt = gc $path
  $c = 0
  $txt[($sl+1)..($el+1)] | % { 

  if ($c -eq 0) { $_.substring($ss-1) } 
  if ($c -gt 0 -and $c -lt $txt[$sl..$el].count ) { $_}
  if ($c -eq ($txt[$sl..$el].count) ) { $_.substring(0,$es+1) } ;

  $c++
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not explain properly. Your script works but see update 1 :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set n=1
set /a start=%4-1
set /a len=%5-%4

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%1") do (
  if !n! gtr %3 exit /b
  if not !n! lss %2 (
    set "row=%%a"
    echo !row:~%start%,%len%!
  )
  set /a n += 1
)
```

**EDIT:** based on your example, I updated my answer, i think you are looking for this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set n=1
set /a startc=%4-1
set /a endc=%5-1

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%1") do (
  set "row=%%a"
  if !n! == %3 (
    if !n! == %2 echo !row:~%startc%,%endc%!
    if not !n! == %2 echo !row:~0,%endc%!
    exit /b
  )
  if !n! == %2  echo !row:~%startc%!
  if !n! gtr %2 echo !row!
  set /a n += 1
)
```

Comment: I am not explain properly. Your script works but see update 1 :)

Comment: Works great :) I vote+ you'r answer but I will accept Christian one because answer first.